# Transaction throughput: POA vs POW in private blockchain networks

Tags: parity, ganache, proof-of-work, proof-of-authority

I know that proof of work is resource intensive, while proof of authority is much faster as no consensus is required since the network is validated by the proper authorities.

But in terms of the transaction throughput in the private blockchain does it make a difference?

I mean, I can notice no difference in speed between a parity POA configured private network and a test ganache network (which should be using POW by default).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I mean, I can notice no difference in speed between a parity POA configured private network and a test ganache network (which should be using POW by default).

Unless you're using Ganache's `--blockTime` option to explicitly set the block time so that it matches a public PoW network<sup>1</sup>, Ganache will instantly mine a new block for every new transaction. This is presumably the default mode of operation to ensure testing can be performed quickly.

> But in terms of the transaction throughput in the private blockchain does it make a difference?

For a fixed block size (block gas limit), and a similar block time to that seen in Ethereum's public mainnet - yes, it should do, with the throughput on PoA being greater than PoW.

[<sup>1</sup> The block time of the public mainnet is currently around 14 seconds.]